# Component auth has not been registered yet - SolidJS & Firebase

Tags: firebase, solid-js

I'm using SolidJS with `solid-firebase` npm package. Just as a test I'm using the code from the git repo but when configured with my firebase project I get the error `Component auth has not been registered yet`

App.tsx

```
import type { Component } from 'solid-js'
import { Match, Switch } from 'solid-js'
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useAuth, useFirebaseApp } from 'solid-firebase'

const Login: Component = () => {
    const app = useFirebaseApp()
    const signIn = () => signInWithPopup(getAuth(app), new GoogleAuthProvider())

    return <button onClick={signIn}>Sign In with Google</button>
}

const App: Component = () => {
    const app = useFirebaseApp()
    const state = useAuth(getAuth(app))

    return (
        <Switch>
            <Match when={state.loading}>
                <p>Loading...</p>
            </Match>
            <Match when={state.error}>
                <Login />
            </Match>
            <Match when={state.data}>
                <h1>Logged In</h1>
            </Match>
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default App
```

index.tsx (firebaseConfig hidden)

```
import { render } from 'solid-js/web'
import { FirebaseProvider } from 'solid-firebase'

import './index.css'
import App from './App'

const root = document.getElementById('root')!
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ...,
    authDomain: ...,
    projectId: ...,
    storageBucket: ...,
    messagingSenderId: ...,
    appId: ...,
    measurementId: ...,
}

if (import.meta.env.DEV && !(root instanceof HTMLElement)) {
    throw new Error(
        'Root element not found. Did you forget to add it to your index.html? Or maybe the id attribute got mispelled?'
    )
}

render(
    () => (
        <FirebaseProvider config={firebaseConfig}>
            <App />
        </FirebaseProvider>
    ),
    root
)
```

The code above is straight from the git repo `https://github.com/wobsoriano/solid-firebase`. Only change is my firebase config.

When I run `npm run dev` and go to `localhost:3000/` I get a blank page with this error in the console.

Comment: Looks like you already opened an issue in the repo. I will just note that there seems to be a mindset of other posts / gh issues about this error (with firebase, without this library).